# django - storing session values after user logout

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-sessions

Using the Django `logout` when the user is logging out all the sessions values get flushed. 
I there a way to keep some of the session values even though the user logs out?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep"?  A session is for a particular user, so when the user logs out, leaving his session doesn't make sense.  If you need to store some values in the db before `django.contrib.auth.logout` flushes the session data, you can do so by simply overriding `django.contrib.auth.views.logout`.

Comment: Here is what want to do. When the user logs out I want to keep the user name in a session variable so when he comes back to the web site I can "recognize" the user so I can see something "hello user".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use cookie instead of session to achieve this.

```
# views.py, login view
# After you have authenticated a user
username = 'john.smith'  # Grab this from the login form

# If you want the cookie to last even if the user closes his browser,
# set max_age to a very large value, otherwise don't use max_age.
response = render_to_response(...)
response.set_cookie('the_current_user', username, max_age=9999999999)
```

In your login view:

```
remembered_username = request.COOKIES.get('the_current_user', '')
```

Push the above to the template to display:

```
Hello {{ remembered_username }}
```

Reference: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie

Comment: I'm getting a "global name 'set_cookie' is not defined". What do I need to import?

Comment: set_cookie is a method of a HttpResponse object, you don't need to import anything.  Can you paste a copy of your sample code?