# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys' in my cart.html in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-sessions

i crated add to cart funtionality for my website what problem i am facing right now is when a user logged in add something to cart and then got to the section od add to cart it load the page and show added items but when a user logged out and again signed in to the site and directly go add to cart page whitout adding any item it shows the above mentioned error i guess that every time it logged session got clear but i don't want it to happen any idea what causing the problem?

my views.py for cart

```
class Cart(View):
    def get (self, request): 
        ids = (list(request.session.get('cart').keys()))
        sections = Section.get_sections_by_id(ids)
        print(sections)
        return render(request, 'cart.html', {'sections': sections})
```

Comment: when setting the ids , check for exceptions and handle them... looks like, Since there is no carts in the session , you cant use the keys() attribute on it... do something like when there are no carts in a session , create one ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persisting session variables across login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256566/persisting-session-variables-across-login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it flushes the session during logout. You can check the source code [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/).
To keep the session you can store the added product in persistent memory. May be you can store in database.

```
[docs]def logout(request):
    """
    Remove the authenticated user's ID from the request and flush their session
    data.
    """
    # Dispatch the signal before the user is logged out so the receivers have a
    # chance to find out *who* logged out.
    user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
    if not getattr(user, 'is_authenticated', True):
        user = None
    user_logged_out.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)

    # remember language choice saved to session
    language = request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)

    request.session.flush()

    if language is not None:
        request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = language

    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
```

**EDIT:**

There can be multiple ways to do this :

1.) You can store it in cookies : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997835/10856970)

2.) Overriding logout method with you custom logout : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809754/10856970)

3.) Use database table to store the cart info.