# any django app that can store sessions ip,browser ..etc and not delete it after the user logout?

Tags: django, session

i want to store the **session** history for users in my application , any app can be used ? if not how some thing like that can be made ?
i want to have complete history for IPS , browsers , location ..etc

i have tried to used `Django-sessions` app from jassband but it the session is deleted after the user logout

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to do this :

1.) You can store it in cookies : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997835/10856970)

```
username = 'john.smith'  # Grab this from the login form

response = render_to_response(...)
response.set_cookie('the_current_user', username, max_age=9999999999)
```

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie).

2.) Overriding logout method with you custom logout : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809754/10856970)

3.) Use database table to store the cart info.

Comment: thanks for your reply but iam sorry , your answer not related to my question . may be iam not clear enough . i want to save the meta information of all users sessions even he logged out like (Ip ,Browser , time ..etc)  for auditing purpose

Comment: As stated above in point no. 2, even If you want to use django-session then, You can override the logout functionality in [this](https://github.com/jazzband/django-user-sessions/blob/master/user_sessions/utils/tests.py) to avoid session delete.

Comment: didnot notice it thanks for the comment again and sorry for my first comment